# Can't edit plugins/sudoers/ins_*.h

Tags: sudo

I am trying to edit the list of insults in Ubuntu which, as described: [How to add a list of insults?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80430/etc-sudoers-insults-how-to-add-a-list-of-insults), which is located in: `plugins/sudoers/ins_*.h`.

I have tried:

```
sudo visudo -f /plugins/sudoers/ins_*.h
```

Which should edit that file according to `visudo` manual page, but it doesn't seem to work.

Output of `ls -al /`:

```
$ ls -al /
total 105
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Feb 21 15:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Feb 21 15:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 13 12:03 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  1024 Feb 21 19:07 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 12 16:41 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4420 Feb 27 23:37 dev
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 Feb 28 00:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Apr 19  2012 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    37 Feb 12 17:14 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-76-generic-pae
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Feb 12 16:43 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x  27 root root  4096 Feb 26 15:51 lib
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb 12 16:32 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 23  2013 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 19  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb 12 18:51 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 191 root root     0 Feb 27 23:36 proc
drwx------  10 root root  4096 Feb 20 20:09 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 21 15:10 .rpmdb
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root   880 Feb 27 23:37 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Feb 13 12:03 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  5  2012 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 23  2013 srv
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Feb 27 23:36 sys
drwxrwxrwt  12 root root  4096 Feb 28 01:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Feb 12 17:51 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Feb 27 19:45 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Feb 12 17:14 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-76-generic-pae
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Feb 12 16:43 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -al /` i.e. do you have `/plugins` directory?

Comment: @heemayl Well no, but I clearly have an insults file somewhere, as the insults easter egg works.

Comment: Ok, then at first you need to find the appropriate directory where the files are..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read again:

> To edit the list of insults, you will need to edit the source and recompile.

So get the source and dependencies:

```
apt-get build-dep sudo
apt-get source sudo
cd sudo*
```

Edit the files. Note that there is no leading slash, since this is a relative path:

```
vim plugins/sudoers/ins_*.h
```

Build:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
```

Install:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../sudo_*.deb
```

Comment: I can't believe that worked! (With a few mods:  I had to build a binary instead with "dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b", and used nano instead of vim).  Thanks!

Comment: @RootFAIL Ah, dammit. Forgot the `-b`.